# How to center the picture list in CollectionView / Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have simple CollectionView to show vertically pictures.
The CollectionView is binded to string list.
I want to show the pictures in the middle of the screen. But they come always at the top of the screen.
Here is my xaml:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackLayout Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                 <Image Source="{Binding .}"/> 
             </StackLayout> 
         </DataTemplate>
     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Important: the count of the pictures is not always the same.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc64m.jpg)

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf1Fk.jpg)

Comment: Can you use Grid instead of StackLayout in your DataTemplate and Check. StackLayout does not mind VerticalOptions

Comment: Can you show me what are you exactly trying to achieve so i can quickly give you a solution?

Comment: Hello @Nikhileshwar I cannot use Grid instead of Stacklayout because the count of the images is not always the same.

Comment: Hello @FreakyAli . I added a screen shot for what i want to do. I have a list of images and delete button. when i click the button an image will be deleted. I want to keep the images in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Whether the whole ColletionView is able to show in the middle of the screen is decided by it's parent screen. If your parent screen is a StackLayout, take a look at this picture: [image]

By default, your stacklayout is set to Orientation="Vertical", so all your effort to adjust children's vertical positions will be ignored.

Correspondingly, if you set Orientation="Horizontal", you won't be able to adjust children's horizontal positions, but you can then make them center in the screen vertically.

so, to put a Label in the middle of the screen you can do this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Delete"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
        <CollectionView WidthRequest="100">
            <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                    <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                    <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        </CollectionView>
        <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need the collection view to bind to the picture list.

Comment: you can try replace the middle Label with your collection view and set your collection view to VerticalOptions="Center" and a proper width, probably it will work.

Comment: @Salah Aldien Alsaleh   hi, I made some change according to your screen shot, basically you just need to change the itemsource to your pictures, remember you need to specify the WidthRequest or it won't work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a collection view `Height` as per the count of the list would work.!

**Xaml:**

```cs
 <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="imageList"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Spacing="10"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <BoxView
                            Margin="10"
                            BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                            HeightRequest="30"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            WidthRequest="30" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
```

**.CS File:**

```cs
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var Imagelist = new List<string>();
            Imagelist.Add("a");
            Imagelist.Add("a");
            Imagelist.Add("a");
            Imagelist.Add("a");
            imageList.ItemsSource = Imagelist;
            imageList.HeightRequest = Imagelist.Count * 40;
        }
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: Unfotunately it did not work. by the way I want to center the picture horiyontally and vertically.

Comment: The images come alyaws at the top of the screen.

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of the same?

Comment: I added the screen shot, please see it.

Comment: Okay, add stack layout before collection view, and make it center aligned

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Take one parent Grid, With three row with height '*' each, Place collection view in 2nd row.

Comment: My app is not easy like this. I did this small page to make my idea clear and prevent complications. I want to know, why the "VerticalOptions" attribute is not working and how to solve this problem

Comment: but it depends on the parent layouts, how u have designed that, will work with vertical option of this component. So Grid would be best option in your case.

Comment: the number of the pictures is not alyaws the same, sometimes one pictuer and sometimes ten, thats why I need the "Center".

Comment: I have updated my answer, and it should work now in your case

Answer (score 0):

Give all the views the maximum amount of space they can have, then just center the image both vertically and horizontally.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}">
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid Padding="10">
                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <Grid.ColumnDefintions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/> 
             </Grid> 
         </DataTemplate>
     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <DataTemplate>
         <StackLayout Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
             <Image Source="{Binding .}"  Aspect="AspectFit"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" /> 
         </StackLayout> 
     </DataTemplate>
```

try to add **Aspect** `Aspect="AspectFit"` Property on your image